# OctoberCMS: How to make the User model notifiable?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, laravel-notification

The `RainLab\User\Models\User` class does not use the `Notifiable` trait and therefore it's not possible to call `notify` or `Notification::send` on it. I want to write a plugin that extends the `RainLab\User\Models\User` and adds `Notifiable` trait to it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implented the trait as a behavior: https://github.com/CptMeatball/notifiable-user

#### How does it work?

This plugin acts as a simple wrapper for the Notifiable trait and adds this as a behavior to the User model. It works by inserting the trait inside the behavior class. It then gets added to the User model during the boot method of the plugin. Simple as that.

**NotifiableBehavior**

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable as NotifiableTrait;
class Notifiable extends \October\Rain\Database\ModelBehavior
{
    use NotifiableTrait;
    public function __call($name, $params = null)
    {
        if (!method_exists($this, $name) || !is_callable($this, $name)) {
            return call_user_func_array([$this->model, $name], $params);
        }
    }
}
```

**Plugin.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    User::extend(function($model) {
        $model->implement[] = 'CptMeatball.NotifiableUser.Behaviors.Notifiable';
    });
}
```

You can use the same principle for any other trait.

Comment: Post the minimal amount of code here rather than in a github repository. Often the github repository gets deleted in hindsight, rendering the answer void.

Comment: Updated the answer @AdnanY . Thanks for the headsup.